# How to retrieve ETHs sent to a contract?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, ether

Lets see this simple contract:

```
contract MyContract {

    receive() external payable {
        require( msg.value > 0 );
        // Thank you but how can I take this ETH later if I need (not now)?
    }

}
```

Lets say I need to store all received ETH and later decide to give it to someone. How to command the Ethereum contract to "transfer" my ETH to someone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, it cannot be done.

One of the important paradigm shifts for an experienced developer is the realization that a contract cannot, and will not, ever do something it wasn't programmed to do. There is no admin access, no direct access to the database (or "state"), and no way to repair anything unless it was proactively inserted into the original contract.

What's missing in the example is some implementation of a withdrawal function. As you consider what it should do, think about who should be able to do it and how much they should be able to withdraw. Absent such instructions, the contract will simply have no procedure for it. This is quite different from logging in as root, changing the code, and exercising privileged access to a database running on an owned server.

Consider:

```
function withdraw() public {
  msg.sender.send(address(this).balance));
}
```

Probably, "anyone can claim and receive it all" isn't satisfactory. Suppose it is a privilege for the deployer:

```
address owner;

constructor() {
  owner = msg.sender;
}

function withdraw() public {
  require(msg.sender == owner, "not the owner");
  msg.sender.send(address(this).balance));
}
```

Maybe partial withdrawals should be allowed:

```
function withdraw(unit amount) public {
  require(msg.sender == owner, "not the owner");
  msg.sender.send(amount);
}
```

The syntax will vary a bit between compiler versions and those are just sketches, so please forgive any minor issues you find. My point is that this is a mode of thinking. You have to anticipate what will *ever* be required and codify the rules of the contract, otherwise, the possibility just isn't there.

The "default setting" is no one has any special privileges - not even the author/deployer/owner. Specific privileges are always codified in the contracts, very explicitly.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Your answer was very useful. But I think my question was not too clear although you may have accidentally responded with ```msg.sender.send(amount);```. What I mean was "where my ETH is stored so I can retrieve it from later?". I know the code I put in answer is very basic and not allow any withdraw maybe just because I don't know from where I can withdraw since I have no "balance[ address ]" here. I see ```msg.sender.send()``` as a magic function that takes ETH from nowhere... Can you explain the mechanism behind store values in a non-token contract?

Comment: Doesn't come from nowhere. It's in `address(this)` which is the contract. If you were to check the balance of the contract address, you would see that it has all money received by the `receive()` function. Someone sends money to contract address 0x1234... and therefore 0x1234 has a positive balance. This is why the previous example uses `address(this).balance` to work out the amount.

Comment: The default behavior is a contract will reject unexpected money. The `receive()` function basically declares that it's okay to receive it instead of rejecting the transaction.

Comment: Hmmm... I see. Look, my vision about this is limited to how tokens work. So I think we need a map store to put holder's balances. In this case we're send ETH (wich is a coin) directly to this contract. Well .... where lives the ETH's in this world? I can command a contract to change the token from one hand to other and it is just a matter of addresses in a map. So.. If I take it right, when I invoke ```msg.sender.send``` I'm actually commanding the (forgive me) "Ethereum Central Bank" to send this ETH from my account to the "sender" account.

Comment: ... and when I "receive" ETH it actually is not here in my contract but in my account there in the blockchain or somewhere over the rainbow in a map store... I see this more like Bitcoin works because there is no tokens there.

Comment: Many thanks Mr. Hitchens. I'll accept your answer but your explanations in comments are much more enlightening.